# Related rates of change - concentric spheres

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Two concentric spheres each have an initial volume of 0. Their radii are increasing at 3mm/s and 5mm/s respectively. Calculate the rate at which the volume between the spheres is changing after 4 seconds.

I end up finding dv/dt = 8*pi*r^2 but I'm not even sure that's right and I'm stuck from there.

Answer (score 2):

The inner radius $r$ and outer radius $R$ (both in mm) depend on time elapsed $t$ (in s) according to
$$
r = 3t \\
R = 5t,
$$
and the volume $V$ (in mm$^3$) is given by
$$
V = \frac{4 \pi}{3} \left( R^3 - r^3 \right).
$$

The multivariable chain rule gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac{dV}{dR} \cdot \frac{dR}{dt} + \frac{dV}{dr} \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} \\
&= 4 \pi R^2 \cdot 5 + 4 \pi r^2 \cdot 3,
\end{align}
$$
and when $t = 4$, the radii are $R = 20$ and $r = 12$,
$$
\left. \frac{dV}{dt} \right|_{t = 4} = 9728 \pi \approx 30561 \text{ mm}^3/\text{s}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, it appears the answer in the book is 19700.

Comment: I managed to get the answer. I started with V=(4/3)π(R^3−r^3) and substituted in R=5t and r=3t. I differentiated that equation and put in t=4, which gave 19700.